# What do you recommend for removing prints from Monoprice Maker Select bed?

Tags: abs, monoprice-maker-select

I've been making some ABS prints, but it's really hard to remove it afterwards.
I've read a lot of different ways of removing it, including using the included chisel/spatula, using air duster, 50/50 alcohol/water, reheating the bed...

I've also read about using a flexible bed that can flex it out. I'm eager to try this approach but don't know what magnetic bed I should get that's compatible with it.

But if you have other tricks for it, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: What is your question? How to install a magnetic bed or how to remove a print? please take the [tour], we are not a forum but a Q&A site: we handle one question per question and don't handle "shopping questions" (questions that source ideas or want to source links) and polls at all.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear in the post. I'm asking how to remove prints from the bed

Answer (score 2):

When all other things have failed, I chuck the build plate in the freezer for half an hour.

The glassplate and the plastic changes size differently when changing temperature and 'pop' it just snaps off easily.

Comment: the maker select does not have a glass bed.  In fact, the bed is pretty much not remove-able.

Comment: @Tal is right about it not being glass. I might be able to unscrew the bed (haven't tried) but then I'd have to re-level it after which is a pain

Comment: (at)Tal & (at)kane are you makers or what, change that build plate ;-) Just kidding, any glass or metal plate would express the same behavior as they change size differently compared to plastics. "PoP!". I have an [Unanswered question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6041/how-can-you-both-reliably-print-and-remove-your-item-without-breaking-it-when-d) about pieces sticking ridiculously to the build plate so I'm eager to know too if magnetic or flexible beds might mitigate this problem! Cheers Valmond

Comment: while cooling a glass plate is a solution if you have a glass plate, this is not a solution for the Monoprice Maker Select.

Comment: @Trish Well, if you add a glass pane to your build plate, you could do it even if you have a Monoprice Maker Select. We are all experimenting with our printers, filaments, build plates, electronics, extruders and so on ... to approach that perfect 3D printer we have in our minds. Which probably means you have to get your hands dirty at some point!

Comment: @Valmond you *can't* add one to that printer without modifying it heavily. The specific question is about a specific printer, and unless you provide how you want to add the glass bed, your answer is not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

After having similar issues to you, and becoming frustrated with having to scrape and pry so much, I bought a removeable magnetic build plate.  I'm not extremely happy with the exact one I purchased, so I won't link it directly, but the concept and general execution is wonderful, compared to the standard build plate on the Maker Select.

Any magnetic build plate that says it's 200x200 should fit, though I'd recommend getting a larger one and cutting it to size - the one I bought is 200x200 exactly and leaves quite a bit of space around the build area that seems like lost space.

Comment: I'm leaning towards the magnetic build plate option. Thanks for your feedback