# How can I remove my print from the bed safely

Tags: heated-bed, print-material, anycubic-i3-mega

I have printed two objects with my new 3D printer (Anycubic Mega S) and everytime, my prints are stuck to my bed (sort of glued to it). I cannot remove them by hand. I have tried waiting until it cools off, but the only thing that works is scraping really hard the bed with the spatula.

I'm scared that if I have to do that for my next prints, I will break the bed (maybe peel off the element that keeps the plastic and the bed glued together while printing).

What is the safest way to remove a print from the bed ?

Comment: I'd recommend a different print surface. After struggling like you, PLA printed on blue tape, we printed a box that seemed welded down!  We had to chisel it off the bed, screwing up the leveling.  Fed up with that, we added a WhamBam system to our printer. It has a magnet that is stuck to the aluminum bed, and a sheet of PEX material that is stuck to a sheet of flex steel.  The magnet holds the flex steel/PEX in place while printing. When the print finishes you pick up the flex steel/PEX, give it a little flex, and the part pops right off. I've posted videos in this forum of parts we've done.

Comment: A tap with the backend of a screwdriver is sometimes enough to get it loose. You can also consider an adhesion spray, not for adhesion, but for release. I used to do that for printing PETG on PEI sheet, without an adhesion spray/glue stick it will bond permanently.

Comment: @CrossRoads I would be very interested in a link of your videos !

Comment: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10176/printing-pla-on-pex-surface-is-heated-bed-needed  Two of my videos here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method that works at our makerspace and also has worked for a user on another 3d printing forum is to use a 50:50 mix of water and denatured alcohol. While the print bed is warm, apply some to the perimeter of the print at the bed surface. Allow it to cool, try to remove the print. If it does not work, reheat the bed and repeat until you are able to release it.

Comment: I will try that tonight :D !

Answer (score 2):

I have had good luck using dental floss. If you can get it under the edge of the print, then you can pull it all the way through and prints come off easily.